# Python - Using the default __hash__ method in __hash__ method definition

Tags: python, methods, hash, magic-methods

I have a class, and I wish to write a `__hash__()` method for this class. The method I want to write will return the default hash of the object in some cases, and a hash of one of its attributes in some others. So, as a simple test case:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
    def __hash__(self):
        if self.bar < 10:
            return hash(self) # <- this line doesn't work
        else:
            return hash(self.bar)
```

The problem with this is that `hash(self)` simply calls `self.__hash__()`, leading to infinite recursion.

I gather that the hash of an object is based on the `id()` of that object, so I could rewrite `return hash(self)` as `return id(self)`, or `return id(self) / 16`, but it seems bad form to me to recreate the default implementation in my own code.

It also occurred to me that I could rewrite it as `return object.__hash__(self)`. This works, but seems even worse, as special methods are not intended to be called directly.

So, what I'm asking is; is there a way to use the default hash of an object without implicitly calling the `__hash__()` method of the class that object is an instance of?

Comment: Calling special methods directly is okay in this situation.  Specifically, when overriding a special method, it's often appropriate to directly call the superclass implementation of that same method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To call parent implementation use:

```
super(Foo, self).__hash__()
```

> It also occurred to me that I could rewrite it as `return
>   object.__hash__(self)`. This works, but seems even worse, as special
>   methods are not intended to be called directly.

You are overriding a magic method, so it's ok to call parent's implementation directly.

Comment: Is this better form than the `object.__hash__(self)` method?

Comment: In this case it is the same. Btw, are you using python 3? If not, you should have `Foo` subclass of `object`.